# Authorization error while connecting to sparql endpoint from python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sparql

I am trying to connect to a private SPARQL endpoint from jupyter notebook. I am new to python and i am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have provided the correct login credentials and yet when I try to process the results , I am getting an error that I am unable to interpret.

I have checked by accessing the endpoint from my browser and running the query manually. It is working fine and I am getting the response without errors too. 
I am not sure what I need to change in the request.py and Wrapper.py to handle this error.

Thank you in advance for the help. Appreciate it.

```
sparql = SPARQLWrapper(" sparql address")
sparql.setHTTPAuth(DIGEST)
sparql.setCredentials("username", "pswd")
sparql.setQuery("""
  --query--
""")
sparql.setReturnFormat(CSV)
results = sparql.query().convert()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ENTER/lib/python3.7/site-packages/SPARQLWrapper/Wrapper.py in _query(self)
    765             else:
--> 766                 response = urlopener(request)
    767             return response, self.returnFormat

/tmp/ENTER/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    221         opener = _opener
--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    223 

/tmp/ENTER/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    530             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 531             response = meth(req, response)
    532 

/tmp/ENTER/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    640             response = self.parent.error(
--> 641                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    642 

/tmp/ENTER/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    568             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 569             return self._call_chain(*args)
    570 

/tmp/ENTER/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    502             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 503             result = func(*args)
    504             if result is not None:

/tmp/ENTER/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    650 

HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unavailable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Unauthorized                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-14dac11c9be4> in <module>
      1 sparql.setReturnFormat(CSV)
      2 
----> 3 results = sparql.query().convert()
      4 
      5 #for result in results["results"]["bindings"]:

/tmp/ENTER/lib/python3.7/site-packages/SPARQLWrapper/Wrapper.py in query(self)
    796             @rtype: L{QueryResult} instance
    797         """
--> 798         return QueryResult(self._query())
    799 
    800     def queryAndConvert(self):

/tmp/ENTER/lib/python3.7/site-packages/SPARQLWrapper/Wrapper.py in _query(self)
    772                 raise EndPointNotFound(e.read())
    773             elif e.code == 401:
--> 774                 raise Unauthorized(e.read())
    775             elif e.code == 500:
    776                 raise EndPointInternalError(e.read())

Unauthorized: Unauthorized: access is denied due to invalid credentials (unauthorized). Check the credentials.
```

PS: I changed the authentication to BASIC and replaced the double quotes in login and password to single quotes and i am getting the json response now. I am not sure if it was the authentication type that was the solution or the server that was overloaded because of which I was not getting a response.

Comment: What does the authentication dialogue look like when you log in with your browser?

Comment: on chrome, it is a pop-up dialogue with username and password.

Comment: Do you know for sure that you ought to be using DIGEST authentication?  If so, the default realm [SPARQLWrapper](https://github.com/RDFLib/sparqlwrapper/blob/master/SPARQLWrapper/Wrapper.py#L448) uses is "SPARQL".  Is that what your private server is expecting?

Comment: the value is " SPARQL" in Wrapper.py for realm. I am not sure if thats what is expected. What could be other forms for Auth? Sorry if thats too obvious.

Comment: which type of authentication is used in your SPARQL endpoint? BASIC or DIGEST?

Comment: I am using BASIC right now and I am still getting a 503 error.

Comment: @FiddleStix  Thank you, for pointing me in the right direction.